# Extend my ASP.NET Core Web API (EF Core) to call a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm very new to Web And API development and I'm trying to build a very simple API to connect to a local SQL database. The ultimate aim will be to push this into Azure and create a Android app for the UI.

I've built my API (With the help of EF Scaffolding) and it works in debug returning the data from the respective DB Tables through my Models and controllers.

However I need to return data from 2 tables (Inner joined), but my scaffolded API only returns data linked to the specific Table EF built..

Ive tried to read several articles but am really struggling and becoming more confused by the day and cant find any useful content that shows a DB first approach - I've adopted for a DB first approach (just because my background is more in the DB space, ill need to run a series of ad hoc queries at a later point against the DB and I'm a little old school in that regard) and so I'm struggling to find a suitable resource to help.

My models & controllers:

Practice Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NSC_API.Models
{
    public partial class Practice
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactAddress { get; set; }
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
        public int? Milage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PracticesController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NSC_API.Models;

namespace NSC_API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PracticesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly NSClinical_DBContext _context;

        public PracticesController(NSClinical_DBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Practices
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Practice>>> GetPractice()
        {
            return await _context.Practice.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Practices/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Practice>> GetPractice(int id)
        {
            var practice = await _context.Practice.FindAsync(id);

            if (practice == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return practice;
        }

        // PUT: api/Practices/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutPractice(int id, Practice practice)
        {
            if (id != practice.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(practice).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PracticeExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Practices
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Practice>> PostPractice(Practice practice)
        {
            _context.Practice.Add(practice);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPractice", new { id = practice.Id }, practice);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Practices/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Practice>> DeletePractice(int id)
        {
            var practice = await _context.Practice.FindAsync(id);
            if (practice == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Practice.Remove(practice);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return practice;
        }

        private bool PracticeExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Practice.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

`WorkItems` model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NSC_API.Models
{
    public partial class WorkItems
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? WiDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? WiStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? WiEndTime { get; set; }
        public int? Practice { get; set; }
        public string Rate { get; set; }
        public string Paid { get; set; }
        public string Revenue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WorkItemsController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NSC_API.Models;

namespace NSC_API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class WorkItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly NSClinical_DBContext _context;

        public WorkItemsController(NSClinical_DBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/WorkItems
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<WorkItems>>> GetWorkItems()
        {
            return await _context.WorkItems.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/WorkItems/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<WorkItems>> GetWorkItems(int id)
        {
            var workItems = await _context.WorkItems.FindAsync(id);

            if (workItems == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return workItems;
        }

        // PUT: api/WorkItems/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutWorkItems(int id, WorkItems workItems)
        {
            if (id != workItems.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(workItems).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!WorkItemsExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/WorkItems
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<WorkItems>> PostWorkItems(WorkItems workItems)
        {
            _context.WorkItems.Add(workItems);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetWorkItems", new { id = workItems.Id }, workItems);
        }

        // DELETE: api/WorkItems/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<WorkItems>> DeleteWorkItems(int id)
        {
            var workItems = await _context.WorkItems.FindAsync(id);

            if (workItems == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.WorkItems.Remove(workItems);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return workItems;
        }

        private bool WorkItemsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.WorkItems.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

In the DB the tables\data are joined in Workitems.Practice inner joined with Practice.ID so my stored procedure simply runs:

```
Select 
    wi.ID, wi.WI_Date, wi.WI_Start_Time, wi.WI_End_Time, PR.Name, Wi.Paid, wi.Revenue
From 
    Work_Items WI 
Inner Join 
    Practice PR On WI.Practice = PR.ID
```

Any help would be VERY much appreciated as I'm really struggling..

Thanks for reading..

Comment: you need to define relationships between your models. check out this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: See following : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class WorkItems
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WiDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WiStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WiEndTime { get; set; }
    public Practice Practice { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
    public string Paid { get; set; }
    public string Revenue { get; set; }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data -----refer this

Comment: this is not really helpful without description

Comment: So the suggestion(if I am interpreting correctly) implies you can only return the data from 2 tables if the entities have a relationship.    Would it not be possible to create a new model and populate with data returned from a stored procedure???